# how to use opencv in dev c++

Tags: c++, opencv, dev-c++

I recently downloaded the opencv library and I need to use it in some code. However I keep on receiving "undefined reference to::" messages and I have tried everything I have found online to fix it with no luck.
Could you give me a run-down of how to configure everything so it works?
Sorry if this is a vague question

Here is an excerpt of the code affected:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctime>

#include         "C:\Users\nideangelis\Desktop\opencv\build\include\opencv2\opencv.hpp"
#include "C:\Users\nideangelis\Desktop\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\core.hpp"
#include "C:\Users\nideangelis\Desktop\opencv\build\include\opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp"
#include "C:\Users\nideangelis\Desktop\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp"
#include "C:\Users\nideangelis\Desktop\CImg_latest\CImg-1.7.5_pre072216\CImg.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv){
//code

cv::Mat Ref;
Ref= cv::Mat(Nxr, Nyr, CV_32FC1, &ref);
int newref[Nxr][Nyr];
cv::Mat Newref;
cv::Mat xii;
xii= cv::Mat((maxX-minX)/dxe+1, (maxY-minY)/dye+1, CV_32FC1, &xi);
cv::Mat yii;
yii= cv::Mat((maxX-minX)/dxe+1, (maxY-minY)/dye+1, CV_32FC1, &yi);
cv::remap(Ref, Newref, xii, yii, CV_INTER_LINEAR);
//code
}
```

Error:

```
C:\Users\NIDEAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccPEwngN.o GammaFML.cpp:(.text+0x29c6): undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
C:\Users\NIDEAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccPEwngN.o GammaFML.cpp:(.text+0x29dc): undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
C:\Users\NIDEAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccPEwngN.o GammaFML.cpp:(.text+0x29f2): undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
C:\Users\NIDEAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccPEwngN.o GammaFML.cpp:(.text+0x2a08): undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
C:\Users\NIDEAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccPEwngN.o GammaFML.cpp:(.text+0x2a45): undefined reference to `cv::remap(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, int, int, cv::Scalar_<double> const&)'
C:\Users\NIDEAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccPEwngN.o GammaFML.cpp:(.text$_ZN2cv3MatD1Ev[_ZN2cv3MatD1Ev]+0x36): undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
C:\Users\NIDEAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccPEwngN.o GammaFML.cpp:(.text$_ZN2cv3MataSERKS0_[_ZN2cv3MataSERKS0_]+0x119): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::copySize(cv::Mat const&)'
C:\Users\NIDEAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccPEwngN.o GammaFML.cpp:(.text$_ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv[_ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv]+0x48): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
C:\Users\nideangelis\Desktop\collect2.exe   [Error] ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: You need to link the libraries

Comment: I have already linked core, highgui and imgproc

Comment: undefined reference to what?

Comment: InputArray, OutputArray, remap, fastFree, Mat::copySize, deallocate

Comment: Please post an example of your code and the exact error you get

Comment: I added the error and the code using opencv

Comment: This is a linker error, you don't link the libraries properly. Btw, where are the includes?

Comment: is it possible that i don't link the proper libraries? x86 instead of x64 or something along those lines?

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't copy them.